# ServiceModelOperation counters do not show up

Tags: wcf, perfmon, performancecounter

We have number of WCF services running on Windows 2008, IIS7, .NET Framework 4.0 (Amazon EC2). 
We can see the counters available in ServiceModelService 4.0.0.0

We are interested in more granular operation level counters so we enabled  in the service.
Yet, despite doing this (also recycle the worker process) operation level (or endpoint counters) are still not showing up in perfmon: only service level are available.

Can you advise what could be the issue?

Thanks,
Piotr

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable them in the config file?

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <diagnostics performanceCounters="All" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

By default the performanceCounters setting is set to ServiceOnly

Also, they will only show up when the service is up and running.

Comment: Hi Chris - Yes, we did. We recycled the service, IIS and we're confident the service is up and being called.

Answer (score 0):

We have moved the same WCF service to Windows 2008 R2 on EC2 and all counters show up properly now. 
Configuration is identical. Perhaps there is some oddity on Windows 2008 SP2 and EC2.